# Animate text with array

Tags: javascript, arrays, animation

I'm trying to animate text with javascript using an array with time intervals e.g.    `t`   `te`  `tex` `text`, I want it to cycle from 0 to 21 and back and I'm not entirely sure how to do it. Any help is muchly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO. As it is written now, your question is unclear. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and follow the guidelines on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Questions here should be specific and concise, and they should show clear research effort and an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**General concept:**
You need to update string output each tick with next value till full string will be visible. Tick interval defines how fast animation is.

One of possible realization below:

```js
// Wait [ms] milliseconds
const Delay = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

// Main function
const main = async () => {
  const p = document.querySelector('p');
  // String you wanna animate
  const targetText = 'Hello there!';
  // Tick interval
  const tick = 60;
  
  // Iterating through string
  for (let i = 1; i <= targetText.length; i++) {
    // Set new value 
    p.innerHTML = ('&nbsp;'.repeat(targetText.length - i) + targetText.slice(-i));
    // Wait for a next tick
    await Delay(tick);
  }
}

main();
```

```css
p {
  font-family: Monospace;
}
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Here are:
`&nbsp;` - space will be visible inside of [.innerHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML);
`tick` - interval between animation frames (in milliseconds);

Refs: [.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), [.repeat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat).